# C# WPF смена локализация приложения через кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf, локализация

Доброго времени суток.

Прошу подсказать как можно реализовать смену локализации приложения через Button или через ComboBox.

В приложении сделал следующие действия.
В файле Resources.resx прописал все названия кнопок, формы и т.п.
После создал два еще два файла Resources.en.resx и Resources.ru-RU.resx, в файле Resources.ru-RU.resx прописал значения на русском.

В самом коде прописал следующее:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        Properties.Settings.Default.Language = "ru-RU";
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }


}
```

Если вначале стоит Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU"); то язык меняется и все отлично, но если реализовывать через нажатие кнопки, то эффекта 0.

В чем моя ошибка или же я не верным путем пошел ?

Comment: Ох, это очень обширная тема и что бы так сделать надо не просто задавать культуру, а писать довольно много [строк кода](https://habr.com/post/274477/) (либо [вот](https://habr.com/post/256193/) тоже пример хороший).

Comment: Надо пробежаться по всем контролам
 и присунуть им новую CultureInfo, потом Invalidate

Comment: Обычно в программах решают такую задачу через запоминание в конфигурации нужного значения `CurrentUICulture`, а затем перезапуск приложения, чтоб изменения вступили в силу. Так сделано даже в самой Visual Studio: зайдите в настройки языка интерфейса и поменяйте значение на новое - и студия проинформирует вас, что необходимо перезапустить студию.

Comment: Чувак, ты бы при старте _(в App.xaml.cs)_ это все делал. Потому что после `InitializeComponent` это двойная работа. Статья на хабре мне помогла, ссылка у @EvgeniyZ выше

Comment: > В проекте в Properties в файле Resources.resx прописал все названия
> кнопок, формы, и т.д После сделал две копии и переименовал их в
> следующие названия: Resources.en.resx и Resources.ru-RU.resx Он же делает всё это автоматически) https://youtu.be/oevqEXCyg3s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодарю за комментарии и вашу помощь.

Решил проблему следующим образом:

1. В проекте в Properties в файле Resources.resx прописал все названия кнопок, формы, и т.д
2. После сделал две копии и переименовал их в следующие названия: Resources.en.resx и Resources.ru-RU.resx
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В файле Resources.ru-RU.resx в столбце Value заменил названия на русский язык.
4. В проекте в разделе  Properties - Settings.settings добавил настройку:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. После в самом в файле Xaml добавил  xmlns:p = "clr-namespace:Localization.Properties"
   И для каждого значения лейбла, формы и т.д в параметре Content меняем на ранее созданные в Resources.resx имена.
   Пример: **< label x:Name = "label" Content = "{x:Static p:Resources.Name}"  HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Margin = "52,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment = "Top" Width = "86"/>**

После проделанных действий добавил следующий код

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.Language);
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i <= LanList.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            if (((ComboBoxItem)LanList.Items.GetItemAt(i)).Content.ToString() == Properties.Settings.Default.Language)
                LanList.SelectedIndex = i;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Language = ((ComboBoxItem)LanList.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }


}
```

В нем реализовано следующее:
В начале я устанавливаю дефолтный язык, в цикле идет определение того языка который сейчас используется программой и последующий вывод значения в ComboBox. 
И в итоге через кнопку после нажатия который происходит смена языка с последующем перезапуском приложения.

В конце компилируем код.

Старался описать более подробно.
Всем больше спасибо.